# Method not working properly when called upon?

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor

I set up a method to increase the age of a Pet by 1 each time its called upon but for some reason, it is giving me the age originally set.

Here is the file with my methods and classes listed:

```
public class Pet
{
    String Name;
    int Age;
    String AdoptionStatus;
    String True="not adopted";
    
    
    public Pet(){
       
    }
    
    public Pet(String Name,int Age){
       this.Name=Name;
       this.Age=Age;

    }
    
    public void SetName(String namesetup){
       
       namesetup=Name;
       
       
    }
    
    public String GetName(){
       
        return Name;
        
    }
    
    public int GetAge(){
        
        return Age;
    }
    
    public int ageincrease(){
        
        return Age+1;
        
    }
    
    public String Getadoptionstatus(){
        
        return AdoptionStatus;
    }
    
    public void Setadoptionstatus(String setadoption2){
       
       AdoptionStatus=True;
       
       
    }
}
```

Here is the other class where the ageincrease() is called but ends up giving me zero:

```
public class MainPets
{
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static String Userinput;

    private static void mainmenu(){
        System.out.println("A."+"  " + "List the pets in the store.");
        System.out.println("B."+"  " + "Age up the pets");
        System.out.println("C."+"  " + "Add a new pet");
        System.out.println("D."+"  " + "Adopt a pet");
        System.out.println("E."+"  " + "Quit");

        Userinput=scan.nextLine();
    }
    
    public static String Getuserinput(){
        
        return Userinput;
    }
    
    
    

    public static void main (String [] args){
        int Pet3age;
        String Pet3name;
        Pet Pet1=new Pet("Fido",3); 
        Pet Pet2=new Pet("furball",1);
        Pet Pet3=null;
        
        System.out.println("Welcome to the pet store.Type the letter to make your selection");
        MainPets.mainmenu();
        
        
        
        
        while (Userinput.equals("E")||Userinput.equals("A")||Userinput.equals("B")||Userinput.equals("C")||Userinput.equals("D")){
            
            
            
            if (Userinput.equals("E")){
                System.out.println("Have a good day!");
                break;
            }

            else if(Userinput.equals("A")){
                System.out.println("Fido is "+Pet1.GetAge()+ " years old and is " + Pet1.Getadoptionstatus());
                System.out.println("furball is " + Pet2.GetAge()+ " years old and is " + Pet2.Getadoptionstatus());
                Userinput=scan.nextLine();
            }

            if(Userinput.equals("B")){
                System.out.println("Everyone just got a little older.");
               Pet1.ageincrease();//Still keeps Pet1 age to 3
               Pet2.ageincrease();//Still keeps Pet2 age to 1
               Userinput=scan.nextLine();
            }

            else if (Userinput.equals("C")){
                System.out.println("Please type in a name");
                Pet3name=scan.nextLine();

                System.out.println("Please type in an age");
                Pet3age=scan.nextInt();
                Userinput=scan.nextLine();
            }

            
        
        
        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry at the top I said it gives me zero when I meant to say that it gave me the original numbers

Comment: You’re returning the increased age but not actually changing `this.Age`.

Comment: How would I fix that?

Comment: `this.Age += 1`?

Comment: Unfortunately, my teacher just wanted me to assign the values in that method and not do anything else. That's why I was supposed to create a separate constructor that increases the age by 1

Comment: What? Your comment makes no sense. `this.Age += 1` is assignment...

Comment: Also your `SetName` method is backwards. `Setadoptionstatus` makes zero sense, with an unused argument. `Getuserinput` is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up the code for you a little bit.

**To answer your question first:**  You were returning the Age of the pet plus 1, not actually asigning a new value to the Pet's Age.  To do this, use `Age++` or `Age = Age + 1` or `Age += 1`.  This should assign a new value to the Pet's age, thus fixing your issue.

Here are the changes I've made:

- Condensed the String declarations to one line
- Fixed `SetName(String namesetup)`.  You had the statment `namesetup=Name`, which assigns the Name field of the class to the instance variable namesetup of the method.  You want to assign what was passed to the method to the class which is done by `Name=namesetup`
- Changed the return statement in `ageincrease()` to `return Age++;` instead of `return Age + 1;`.  This is the same as `Age = Age + 1;`
- Replaced the long `while` loop in the main class with a `switch` statement and a `while` loop.  This is convenient because you don't need a long condition check in the while loop. I used a flag variable that flags when the user inputs `"E"`. If you're unfamiliar with `switch` statements, then you can readup on them [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Notes and concerns:

- With your current code, you check for the condition `Userinput.equals("D")` in the while loop, but you have nothing in the while loop to handle that condition, which leaves a possibility for an infinite loop.
- I'm not going to change the names of your variables or methods, but you should know that the convention is variableName, where the first word is lowercase and the all the following have the first letter uppercased.  Your variable and method names are inconsitent with this convention in your code, which can make it confusing for other coders to read and use.  Following this convention is a good coding practice that can save you headaches on larger projects.

Here's your edited Pet class:

```
public class Pet {
    String Name, AdoptionStatus, True = "not adopted";
    int Age;

    public Pet() {}

    public Pet(String Name, int Age) {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Age = Age;
    }

    public void SetName(String namesetup) {
        Name = namesetup;
    }

    public String GetName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public int GetAge() {
        return Age;
    }

    public int ageincrease() {
        return Age++;
    }

    public String Getadoptionstatus() {
        return AdoptionStatus;
    }

    public void Setadoptionstatus(String setadoption2) {
        AdoptionStatus = True;
    }

}
```

And here's what I replaced the your while loop with:

```
int flag = 0;
    while(flag != -1) {
        switch(Userinput) {
            case "A": 
                System.out.println("Fido is "+Pet1.GetAge()+ " years old and is " + Pet1.Getadoptionstatus());
                System.out.println("furball is " + Pet2.GetAge()+ " years old and is " + Pet2.Getadoptionstatus());
                Userinput=scan.nextLine();
                break;
            case "B":
                System.out.println("Everyone just got a little older.");
                Pet1.ageincrease();//Still keeps Pet1 age to 3
                Pet2.ageincrease();//Still keeps Pet2 age to 1
                System.out.println(Pet1.GetAge() + " " + Pet2.GetAge());
                Userinput=scan.nextLine();
                break;
            case "C":
                System.out.println("Please type in a name");
                Pet3name=scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please type in an age");
                Pet3age=scan.nextInt();
                Userinput=scan.nextLine();
                break;
            case "D":
                //Not sure how you want to implement this
                break;
            case "E":
                flag = -1;
                break;
            }
    }
```